# Jboss 5 debug mode goes in continuous listening mode and doing nothing

Tags: java, jboss, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug maven project in IntelliJ, it gives me

1. Jboss server starteted with `JAVA_OPTS = %JAVA_OPTS% -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=y`

   Jboss server goes in listinini mode

   Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
   Log, data, tmp and work folder is not created
2. How to configure IntelliJ 11 for Jboss debug

Comment: Connect to the server with the debugger using JBoss Remote debug configuration in IDEA, or don't enable suspend mode if you want the server to start without debugger connection.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks It solve my one problem. How do I configure IntelliJ maven project with remote jboss debugging. if you have any link could you share the link.

Comment: See also http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Debugging_applications_for_JBoss_AS_in_IntelliJ_IDEA_9_or_10